# mysql query - pairs of repeating numbers

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database with 2 columns (ex: no_1, no_2) and then 5000 rows of data, numbers are between 1 - 20 , I need to find a pairs of numbers which where repeating the most of the times? 
Any help please ?

Comment: Define "repeating". In a row? In what order? Or do you mean simply how often. The combination of the columns? And what have you tried to solve the problem? Where did you get stuck? SO is no code factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:-

```
SELECT no_1, no_2, COUNT(*) AS numbercount
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY no_1, no_2
ORDER BY numbercount DESC
```